# How to treat a string a character in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to find all occurrence of the word `function`, with some limitations:

1. no other `\w` before it.
2. no `.` before it.
3. no string `def`' before it.

I've managed to get the first 2 with this:

```
r'(?<![.\w])function'
```

how can add the other condition?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what you would like to match?

Comment: i've change my phrasing, is it clearer now?

Comment: @YanivHaddad are you concerned with whether there is whitespace between the `.`, `\w` or `def` and the string `function`?

Comment: This is used to match python code.  i'm looking to match a certain function which is not call from anywhere so i don't want to match any thing like: lib.function, so here i don't care about whitespace. any normal character before it may indicate this is a different word, so here whitespace not matter also. But in the def case, i want to make sure this is not a function defined locally, so care about the whitespace. I don't want to match 'def function'. thanks @LeonardChallis

Answer (score 0):

You might add another negative lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is not a whitespace followed by `def`:

[`(?<![.\w])(?<!def )function`](https://regex101.com/r/cyHBBv/1)

Note that this only matches a single whitespace.

Maybe you could use an alternation and first match what you do not want to match and capture in a group what you do want to match:

[`def +function|[.\w]function|(function\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/ilThYU/1)